# How to specify destination directory in Makefile.PL

Tags: perl, makefile, cpan, makemaker

I am using ExtUtils::MakeMaker; to generate makefile. It runs gcc on my cpp files but copies my object files to current directory. How do i specify the destination folder where my .o files will be stored. I had mentioned the .o files in the OBJECT field.

OBJECT"   => "des_dir/abc.o"

I get this error when i run the makefile

gcc: des_dir/abc.o: No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: Why do you care where the `.o` files are? They are **not** installed.

Comment: I had mentioned them in OBJECT field, it looking for them.

Comment: please include your current Makefile.PL, and explain in more detail what you are trying to install?